# How to add respective comment for each file on Sourcetree?

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

The Sourcetree is a version control tool, the user can add a comment in a text box for the commit.

But is it possible to add the comment for specific files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment you can add is the commit message. The commit message belongs to the commit you make not to any file so you can't add file specific comments.
If you want you can commit each file alone. Then you can have a message for each commit and each commit contains only one file.

Comment: Is there no version control tool be able to write the comment for specific files?